# mercurial ignore files

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

How do I ignore everything in a bin folder which is inside different projects?

easy way -

```
^projects/a/bin/*$
^projects/b/bin/*$
```

I wanted to do something like -

```
^projects/*/bin/*$
```

But the above does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that a valid regex you need:

```
^projects/.*/bin/.*$
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest is this:

```
glob:bin/
glob:obj/
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use glob syntax for .hgignore to do such things even simpler:

```
syntax: glob
projects/*/bin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore the specified folders at a fixed level I'm using something like this:

```
syntax: regexp
(?i)^projects/[^/]*/bin/
```